# Cómo convertir un String a Entero en Java?

Tags: java, android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Como puedo hacer para convertir un String a Int en java

Ejemplo:

```
public static String OPERACION="5+6-8";

public static int RESULTADO=0;
```

Estoy haciendo una calculadora,cuando se presiona una tecla está la almaceno en una variable estática de tipo string, e intentado con:

```
RESULTADO=Integer.parseInt(OPERACION);
```

Pero al ejecutar la aplicación y presionar el botón de resultado se me detiene la aplicación.

Este es el Codigo:

```
package com.uso.evaluaciontwo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Calculadora extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView txvResultado, txvOperacion;
    Button btnDEL, btnAC, btnMas, btnMenos, btnPor, btnEntre, btnIgual, btnPunto, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn0;
    public static String OPERACION = "";
    public static int RESULTADO = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculadora);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("HS16-I04-001");
        }
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6 = findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7 = findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8 = findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9 = findViewById(R.id.btn9);
        btn0 = findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        btnAC = findViewById(R.id.btnAC);
        btnDEL = findViewById(R.id.btnDEL);
        btnMenos = findViewById(R.id.btnMenos);
        btnMas = findViewById(R.id.btnMas);
        btnEntre = findViewById(R.id.btnEntre);
        btnPor = findViewById(R.id.btnPor);
        btnIgual = findViewById(R.id.btnIgual);
        txvOperacion = findViewById(R.id.txvOperacion);
        txvResultado = findViewById(R.id.txvResultado);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn9.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn0.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAC.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDEL.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMenos.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMas.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnEntre.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPor.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnIgual.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn0:
                OPERACION = OPERACION + "0";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btn1:
                OPERACION = OPERACION + "1";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                OPERACION = OPERACION + "2";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btn3:
                OPERACION = OPERACION + "3";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btn4:
                OPERACION = OPERACION + "4";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btn5:
                OPERACION = OPERACION + "5";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btn6:
                OPERACION = OPERACION + "6";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btn7:
                OPERACION = OPERACION + "7";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btn8:
                OPERACION = OPERACION + "8";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btn9:
                OPERACION = OPERACION + "9";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btnDEL:
                if(OPERACION.length() > 0) {
                    OPERACION = OPERACION.substring(0, OPERACION.length() - 1);
                    txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                }else{

                }
                break;
            case R.id.btnAC:
                OPERACION = "";
                txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                break;
            case R.id.btnMas: {
                if (!OPERACION.isEmpty()) {
                    if (OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("+") | OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals(".")) {

                    } else if (OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("*") | OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("-") | OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("/")) {
                        OPERACION = OPERACION.substring(0, OPERACION.length() - 1);
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                        OPERACION = OPERACION + "+";
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                    } else {
                        OPERACION = OPERACION + "+";
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
            case R.id.btnMenos:{
                if (!OPERACION.isEmpty()) {
                    if (OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("-") | OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals(".")) {

                    } else if (OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("+")) {
                        OPERACION = OPERACION.substring(0, OPERACION.length() - 1);
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                        OPERACION = OPERACION + "-";
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                    } else {
                        OPERACION = OPERACION + "-";
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                    }
                }else{
                    OPERACION=OPERACION+"-";
                    txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                }
            }
                break;
            case R.id.btnPor: {
                if (!OPERACION.isEmpty()) {
                    if (OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("*") | OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals(".")) {

                    } else if (OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("-") |
                            OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("+") |
                            OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("/")) {

                        OPERACION = OPERACION.substring(0, OPERACION.length() - 1);
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                        OPERACION = OPERACION + "*";
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                    } else {
                        OPERACION = OPERACION + "*";
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                    }
                }
            }
                break;
            case R.id.btnEntre:{
                if (!OPERACION.isEmpty()) {
                    if (OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("/") | OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals(".")) {

                    } else if (OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("-") |
                            OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("+") |
                            OPERACION.substring(OPERACION.length() - 1).equals("*")){

                        OPERACION = OPERACION.substring(0, OPERACION.length() - 1);
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                        OPERACION = OPERACION + "/";
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                    } else {
                        OPERACION = OPERACION + "/";
                        txvOperacion.setText(OPERACION);
                    }
                }
            }
                break;
            case R.id.btnIgual:
                RESULTADO=Integer.parseInt(OPERACION);
                txvOperacion.setText(RESULTADO);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En este caso te recomiendo usar Rhino Script Engine, revisa como implementar esta library y los import correctos a usar para que puedas obtener el resultado que deseas,, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deseas realizar es similar a lo que realiza la clase `ScriptEngine` en JavaX

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Sin embargo para el caso de Android, esto no puede realizarse de esta forma mediante el SDK, en este caso lo ideal en este caso es realizar las operaciones con valores de tipo `int` pero no con variables tipo `String`.

**Sin embargo otra opción para evaluar una operación como la que indicas `"5+6-8"` , es usar [Rhino Script Engine for Android](https://github.com/APISENSE/rhino-android)** este es un ejemplo,

Implementa la library definiendola en tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
  implementation 'io.apisense:rhino-android:1.0'
```

Usa los  imports:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
```

ejemplo:

```
           String Operation = "5+4-2";
           ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");

            try {
               Object result = engine.eval(Operation);
                Log.d("Calculator", "Operation: " + Operation + " result: " + result);
            } catch (ScriptException e) {
                Log.d("Calculator", " ScriptEngine error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Output:

```
Operation: 5+4-2 result: 7.0
```

---

Para el caso de tu clase, este sería el cambio usando [Rhino Script Engine for Android](https://github.com/APISENSE/rhino-android) :

```
  ...
  ...
            case R.id.btnIgual:

                ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");
                Object resultado = null;
                try {
                   resultado = engine.eval(OPERACION);
                } catch (ScriptException e) {
                    Log.d("Calculadora", " ScriptEngine error: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                //*NO realizar parsing mediante Integer.parseInt(...),
                //Ya que se perderían los valores con puntos decimales.
                txvOperacion.setText(resultado.toString());
                break;
  ...
  ...
```

Revisa mi respuesta:

[How to use ScriptEngineManager in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58646631/250260)

Answer (score 0):

No es posible hacerlo de la manera que lo has planteado, ya cuando se hace el parse de esa operación se generará una excepción, prácticamente lo que haces es esto.

```
String operacion = "4+1+2+5+6-1";//
int RESULTADO = Integer.parseInt(operacion);
```

Intenta lo siguiente

```
case R.id.btnIgual:
    Object result;
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
    try{
        result = engine.eval(OPERACION);
        RESULTADO=Integer.parseInt(result.toString);
    }catch(ScriptException ex){
        Log.e("Error",ex.getMessage());
    }
    txvOperacion.setText(RESULTADO);
    break;
```

Prácticamente lo que se hace es ejecutar un script de Javascript(JS), es decir evalua el String de la operación mediante JS y te regresa el resultado de la operación

Comment: Por cierto, ese código lo puedes poner mas bonito, sacando las variable a que sean globales ya que las usaras cada que haces una operación, si las dejas ahí, a cada momento del igual generarías una nueva instancia y asignarias otro espacio de memoria al momento de presionar el igual.